# How to determine payload size from header?

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, send, recv

I want to send() body and header which has body size from the Side A.
On the Side B, in the first recv() header to determine the size of payload. The second, recv() body.

I tried to use recv() twice but could not through the second recv() function.

Side A

```
struct CommandHeader_t {
    int BodySizeByte;
};

void Send()
{
    const int BODY_SIZE_BYTE = 10;
    CommandHeader_t* header_ptr = (CommandHeader_t*) malloc(sizeof(CommandHeader_t) + BODY_SIZE_BYTE);
    header_ptr->BodySizeByte = BODY_SIZE_BYTE;

    char* body_ptr = (char*) (header_ptr + sizeof(CommandHeader_t));
    snprintf(body_ptr, BODY_SIZE_BYTE, "Hello World");

    int sock = socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_un addr = {0};
    addr.sun_family = AF_LOCAL;
    strcpy(addr.sun_path, SENDING_SOCKET);
    sendto(sock, header_ptr, sizeof(CommandHeader_t) + BODY_SIZE_BYTE, 0, (const struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    close(sock);
}
```

Side B

```
void Reveice()
{
    // something
    CommandHeader_t header;
    char* body_ptr;
    recv(sockfd, &header, sizeof(CommandHeader_t), 0);
    body_ptr = (char*) malloc(header.BodySizeByte);
    recv(sockfd, body_ptr, header.BodySizeByte, 0); // CANNOT recv anything
}
```

Comment: Looks like you sent a single datagram, with the header and content. The receiver received the datagram, but `recv()` only indicates the size of the header. The rest of the datagram, thusly, was thrown away and discarded. Hence, no soup for you, in the 2nd recv.

Comment: Recommendation: Don't ignore return codes. They almost always contain important information like, "How many bytes of data did I really get?" or "Did I get anything?" and the ever popular, "Hey, is my socket still alive?".

Comment: As this is UDP, which you failed to even mention, there is no need to send the payload size. The return value of `recv()` already provides it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code:

On the sending side, you are not doing pointer arithmetic correctly when assigning the `body_ptr` pointer.  As `header_ptr` is declared as `CommandHeader_t*`, doing `(header_ptr + sizeof(CommandHeader_t))` will calculate a memory address that is `sizeof(CommandHeader_t)` number of `CommandHeader_t` elements past the address that `header_ptr` is pointing at.  That is not what you want.  You need to instead calculate an address that is `sizeof(CommandHeader_t)` number of `char`s past the `header_ptr` address.

So, you need to change this:

```
char* body_ptr = (char*) (header_ptr + sizeof(CommandHeader_t));
```

To this instead:

```
char* body_ptr = ((char*) header_ptr) + sizeof(CommandHeader_t);
```

A simpler way to handle this is to add a `char[1]` member to `CommandHeader_t`, and then subtract 1 when `malloc()`'ing it, eg:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) // or equivalent
struct CommandHeader_t {
    int BodySizeByte;
    char data[1];
};
#pragma pack(pop) // or equivalent

CommandHeader_t* header_ptr = (CommandHeader_t*) malloc(offsetof(CommandHeader_t, data) + BODY_SIZE_BYTE);
header_ptr->BodySizeByte = BODY_SIZE_BYTE;

char* body_ptr = header_ptr->data;
snprintf(body_ptr, BODY_SIZE_BYTE, "Hello World");
```

Also, since you are using `SOCK_DGRAM` on the sending side, the `sendto()` is message-oriented, sending the entire data in 1 message.  But your receiving code is written as if it were using a stream-oriented socket instead.  Don't mismatch socket types like that.  If you want to call `recv()` multiple times, use a stream-oriented socket on both sides.  Otherwise, use a message-oriented socket on both sides, and then have the receiver allocate a buffer large enough to receive an entire message in 1 `recvfrom()` (you can use `ioctl(FIONREAD)` to determine the size of the next pending message), and then parse the contents of that message as needed.

Also, your receiver is leaking the `body_ptr` buffer it allocated with `malloc()`.